# What items i need to dispose in each activity?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

What items i need to dispose in each activity for free memory?
I'm using recyclerview,listview,textview,edidtext and buttons.

Is it good practice to set them null on destroy method?

```
 private List<InventoryPreviewClass> mItems;
private ListView mlistview;
private EditText mSearch;
private EditText etSearchAlwaysOn;
private LinearLayout mContainer;
private bool mAnimatedDown;
string dpPath;
private bool mIsAnimating;
private MyListViewAdapterInventory mAdapter;

SQLiteConnection db;
private TextView mTxtHeaderFirstName;
private TextView mTxtHeaderLastName;
private bool mFirstNameAscending;
private bool mLastNameAscending;
List<String> ID;
List<String> Name;
Spinner CategorySpinner;

protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    mItems = null;
    mlistview = null;
    mSearch = null;
    etSearchAlwaysOn = null;
    mContainer = null;

    dpPath = null;
    mAdapter = null;
    db = null;
    mTxtHeaderFirstName = null;
    mTxtHeaderLastName = null;
    ID = null;
    Name = null;
    CategorySpinner = null;


}
```

Is there need to dispose them all? Or it will automatically dispose those items if there no in use?

Comment: You can set them to null, but it's not needed. Once an activity is destroyed, everything gets gcc'd. The only part you need to be careful, generally speaking, is not to keep a reference (somewhere else) to an activity, because otherwise it won't be destroyed at all, and therefore the used components won't be gcc'd. For instance don't use the activity passed to a singleton utility helper to have access to Context, but instead take the application context from it: _MyHelper(Context ctx) { mAppCtx = ctx.getApplicationContext() }_.

Comment: Thank you, so when i call finish it will automatically destroy my objects above right? What you mean reference ? Also it has to do also with mobile number? I notice that some mobile have different behaviours how they manage gc collector.

Comment: When you call finish() it will mark them to be gcc'd, but they will be destroyed according to the gcc strategy whenever the gcc wants. Reference I mean _reference_, like your _mItems_ is a reference to a list (in C/C++ you'll call it pointer, in Java you'll call it reference). Also, yes, each Android's manufacturer can, theoretically, do any change it wants to the system; you can test against default behavior only on vanilla droid, like in Nexus and Pixel phones.

Comment: So my list need to be set null when i'm destroy my activity?

Comment: "You can set them to null, but it's not needed" I quote myself :)

Comment: But you said that mitems is a reference to a list...

Comment: To be verbose: in both cases (setting references to null before to call finish()) the objects will be gccd. The only case where you want to be careful that that won't happen, is when another class keeps a reference to your Activity, which you don't want to (namely a memory leak). So, to avoid this case, make sure that you don't keep ever references to Activities, but keep instead references to the application context. I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Note: when you call finish(), from the system point of view the objects are not destroyed immediately, included your activity, they are kept around as long as the system want and need. So if your activity is referenced from another part of your code (so it could be accessed any moment at runtime) then the system cannot gcc it, neither it can destroy it ever. In such case, if you set your inner references to null, those objects will be gcc'd, but if runtime code will access them, your app will crash with an NPE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181659/discussion-between-dim-and-alessio).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. What items i need to dispose in each activity for free memory? I'm using recyclerview,listview,textview,edidtext and buttons.
2. Is it good practice to set them null on destroy method?
3. Is there need to dispose them all? Or it will automatically dispose those items if there no in use?

To answer your questions:

1. None of them.
2. No, it's not a good practice, and it's not needed. What is a good practice instead is not to keep a reference to any passed activity, which will cause memory leaks, and also won't allow the system to destroy the activity itself. When in need to keep a reference to a passed activity, keep a reference to the application context instead:

   ```
   public class MyHelper {
   private static MyHelper instance;     // for instance singleton helper
   private final Context mContext;

   private MyHelper(@NonNull Context context) {
       mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. No need. The system will gcc them when needed. The system will also kill your app and your process, at any moment, in case its short in memory, but at that point it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: I'm using a class in each activity. Inside this class i'm using 'private static strings' which are called also in each activity

Comment: The only cleanup i'd worry about is removing things like broadcast listeners that still have a handle to the activity that would prevent the activity from getting garbage collected.  This also includes operations like disposing of any rx Disposable subscriptions you might have, removing LiveData observers, etc...